# Creating one XML file for each row in Excel sheet, based on predefined XML structure

Tags: python, excel, xml, elementtree

I have the following XML file and would like to import data from an Excel spreadsheet to be placed between certain elements such as `eadid` and `titleproper`. I've tried the attached Python code but this produced an XML file that did not include the full schema. I want to save each row of data in the Excel file to a separate XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ead xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd">
<eadheader>
    <eadid></eadid>
    <filedesc>
    <titlestmt>
        <titleproper></titleproper>
    </titlestmt>
    </filedesc>
    <profiledesc>
        <langusage>
            <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn"></language>
        </langusage>
    </profiledesc>
    </eadheader>
        <archdesc level="fonds">
            <did>
                <unitid></unitid>
                <langmaterial>
                    <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn"></language>
                </langmaterial>
                <unittitle></unittitle>
                <unitdate normal=""></unitdate>
                <physdesc>
                    <extent>1 Cubic Feet</extent>
                </physdesc>
                <langmaterial>
                    <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn">English</language>
                </langmaterial>
            </did>
            <dsc>
            </dsc>
        </archdesc>
</ead>
```

This is the code I have tried in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
pip install openpyxl
from lxml import etree as et
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xet
tree = et.parse('test_resource.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
raw_data = pd.read_excel(r'/Users/smeyerkukan/Desktop/ArchivesSpace/Python Coding/aspace.xlsx')
tree = et.parse('test_resource.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for row in raw_data.iterrows():
    root_tags = et.SubElement(root, 'ExportData')
    Column_heading_1 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'titleproper')
    Column_heading_2 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'unittitle')
    Column_heading_3 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'eadid')
    Column_heading_4 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'unitid')
    Column_heading_7 = et.SubElement(root_tags, 'unitdate')
    Column_heading_1.text = str(row[1]['<titleproper>'])
    Column_heading_2.text = str(row[1]['<unittitle>'])
    Column_heading_3.text = str(row[1]['<eadid>'])
    Column_heading_4.text = str(row[1]['<unitid>'])
    Column_heading_7.text = str(row[1]['<unitdate>'])
tree = et.ElementTree(root)
et.indent(tree, space="\t", level=0)
tree.write('output.xml', encoding="utf-8")
```

This is the output I would like to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ead xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd">
<eadheader>
    <eadid>Church RG 095</eadid>
    <filedesc>
    <titlestmt>
        <titleproper>Salem Reformed Church (Philadelphia, PA)</titleproper>
    </titlestmt>
    </filedesc>
    <profiledesc>
        <langusage>
            <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn"></language>
        </langusage>
    </profiledesc>
    </eadheader>
        <archdesc level="fonds">
            <did>
                <unitid>Church RG 095</unitid>
                <langmaterial>
                    <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn"></language>
                </langmaterial>
                <unittitle>Salem Reformed Church (Philadelphia, PA)</unittitle>
                <unitdate normal="1811/2003"></unitdate>
                <physdesc>
                    <extent>1 Cubic Feet</extent>
                </physdesc>
                <langmaterial>
                    <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn">English</language>
                </langmaterial>
            </did>
            <dsc>
            </dsc>
        </archdesc>
</ead>
```

This is the output I received:

```
    <ExportData>
    <titleproper>Salem Reformed Church (Philadelphia, PA)</titleproper>
    <unittitle>Salem Reformed Church (Philadelphia, PA)</unittitle>
    <eadid>Church RG 095</eadid>
    <unitid>Church RG 095</unitid>
    <unitdate>1811/2003</unitdate>
</ExportData>
<ExportData>
    <titleproper>First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, Pa.)</titleproper>
    <unittitle>First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, Pa.)</unittitle>
    <eadid>Church RG 001</eadid>
    <unitid>Church RG 001</unitid>
    <unitdate>1843/2019</unitdate>
</ExportData>
<ExportData>
    <titleproper>Christ Reformed Church (Allentown, PA)</titleproper>
    <unittitle>Christ Reformed Church (Allentown, PA)</unittitle>
    <eadid>Church RG 002</eadid>
    <unitid>Church RG 002</unitid>
    <unitdate>1876/1982</unitdate>
</ExportData>
```

Here is a screenshot of the Excel file I am using. There are 916 rows in total:

[image: Screenshot of the Excel file]

Comment: Please, don’t post an image of the code. You have to insert your python code into a code block in stackoverflow instead. How looks your Excel. Please share a dummy example,too and your expected output XML.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've made those updates and hopefully that will be helpful.

Comment: I just posted some of the output. I am referring the full tree not being replicated as the xml schema.

Comment: When you say "This is the output I would like to get", do you actually mean "I would like to create 916 XML files with the following structure (one file for each row in the Excel sheet)"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I would like - 916 xml files with the original structure and one file for each row in the Excel sheet. Just can't seem to figure out how to get the data from each row in the Excel sheet to automate into the correct places.

Comment: You import `xml.etree.ElementTree`, but you don't actually use it (you use lxml instead and that is fine). A command such as "pip install openpyxl" does not belong in a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

### OPTION 1 with CSV:

If you can save your Excel as a csv-file you don't need pandas.
I would suggest a function which fills your empty xml template and save it to disk with the row number as file id.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

def create_XML(row, no):
    # Your Template ead.xml will be modified with row data.
    # Register namespaces
    # ns = dict(node for event, node in ET.iterparse('ead.xml', events = ['start-ns']))
    ns = {'': 'urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9', 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
    for prefix, uri in ns.items():
        ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
        
    tree = ET.parse('ead.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    titleproper = root.find('.//titleproper', ns)
    titleproper.text = row[0]
  
    unittitle = root.find('.//unittitle', ns)
    unittitle.text = row[1]
    
    eadid = root.find('.//eadid', ns)
    eadid.text = row[2]
    
    unitid = root.find('.//unitid', ns)
    unitid.text = row[3]
    
    unitdate = root.find('.//unitdate', ns)
    unitdate.attrib['normal'] = row[4]
    # If you remove the hash sign on the next two code rows you get a format like: <unitdate normal="1811/2003 " unitdatetype="inclusive">1811-2003 </unitdate>
    # unitdate.attrib['unitdatetype'] = "inclusive"
    # unitdate.text = row[4].replace('/','-')
    
    
    new_tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    ET.indent(root, space='  ')
    new_tree.write(f"{no}_book.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    print(f"{no}_book.xml written!")
    

# Export the Excel to csv with ';' - delimiter e.g:
# <titleproper>;<unittitle> ;<eadid> ;<unitid> ;BeginDate;EndDate;<unitdate>
# Row_No for filename of each CSV row
no = 1
with open("Biblio.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    book = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    next(book, None)
    for row in book:
        line = ' '.join(row).split(';')
        row_xml = [line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[6]]
        create_XML(row_xml, no)
        no += 1
```

Output example file from 2nd row:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ead xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd">
  <eadheader>
    <eadid>Church RG 001</eadid>
    <filedesc>
      <titlestmt>
        <titleproper>First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, PA.)</titleproper>
      </titlestmt>
    </filedesc>
    <profiledesc>
      <langusage>
        <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn" />
      </langusage>
    </profiledesc>
  </eadheader>
  <archdesc level="fonds">
    <did>
      <unitid>Church RG 001</unitid>
      <langmaterial>
        <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn" />
      </langmaterial>
      <unittitle>First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, PA.)</unittitle>
      <unitdate normal="1843/2019" />
      <physdesc>
        <extent>1 Cubic Feet</extent>
      </physdesc>
      <langmaterial>
        <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn">English</language>
      </langmaterial>
    </did>
    <dsc />
  </archdesc>
</ead>
```

My CSV looks like:

```
<titleproper>;<unittitle> ;<eadid> ;<unitid> ;BeginDate;EndDate;<unitdate>
Salem Reformed Church (Philadelphia, PA);Salem Reformed Church (Philadelphia, PA) ;Church RG 095 ;Church RG 095 ;1811;2003;1811/2003 
First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, PA.);First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, PA.);Church RG 001;Church RG 001;1843;2019;1843/2019
```

If you would use a [better format](https://eadiva.com/unitdate/) you can add some lines more:

**For format like this**: `<unitdate normal="1811/2003" unitdatetype="inclusive">1811-2003</unitdate>`

```
unitdate = root.find('.//unitdate', ns)
unitdate.attrib['normal'] = row[4]
unitdate.attrib['unitdatetype'] = "inclusive"
unitdate.text = row[4].replace('/','-')
```

### OPTION 2 with PANDAS:

Additional here a solution **with pandas**. CAUTION .xls is not supported! Use .xlsx instead, please. I have used here the extended format for `<unitdate>`. You can comment it out, if you don't like it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

def create_XML(row, no):
    # Your Template ead.xml will be modified with row data.
    # Register namespaces
    # ns = dict(node for event, node in ET.iterparse('ead.xml', events = ['start-ns']))
    ns = {'': 'urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9', 'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
    for prefix, uri in ns.items():
        ET.register_namespace(prefix, uri)
        
    tree = ET.parse('ead.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    titleproper = root.find('.//titleproper', ns)
    titleproper.text = row[0]
  
    unittitle = root.find('.//unittitle', ns)
    unittitle.text = row[1]
    
    eadid = root.find('.//eadid', ns)
    eadid.text = row[2]
    
    unitid = root.find('.//unitid', ns)
    unitid.text = row[3]
    
    unitdate = root.find('.//unitdate', ns)
    unitdate.attrib['normal'] = row[4]
    unitdate.attrib['unitdatetype'] = "inclusive"
    unitdate.text = row[4].replace('/','-')
     
    new_tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
    ET.indent(root, space='  ')
    new_tree.write(f"{no}_book.xml", xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
    print(f"{i+1}_book.xml written!")
    
df = pd.read_excel("Biblio.xlsx")
for i in range(len(df)):
    row_xml = [df.iloc[i,0], df.iloc[i,1], df.iloc[i,2], df.iloc[i,3], df.iloc[i,6]]
    create_XML(row_xml, i+1)
```

Output here with extended `<unitdate>`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ead xmlns="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:isbn:1-931666-22-9 http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd">
  <eadheader>
    <eadid>Church RG 001</eadid>
    <filedesc>
      <titlestmt>
        <titleproper>First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, PA.)</titleproper>
      </titlestmt>
    </filedesc>
    <profiledesc>
      <langusage>
        <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn" />
      </langusage>
    </profiledesc>
  </eadheader>
  <archdesc level="fonds">
    <did>
      <unitid>Church RG 001</unitid>
      <langmaterial>
        <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn" />
      </langmaterial>
      <unittitle>First Zion Lehigh Union Church (Alburtis, PA.)</unittitle>
      <unitdate normal="1843/2019" unitdatetype="inclusive">1843-2019</unitdate>
      <physdesc>
        <extent>1 Cubic Feet</extent>
      </physdesc>
      <langmaterial>
        <language langcode="eng" scriptcode="Latn">English</language>
      </langmaterial>
    </did>
    <dsc />
  </archdesc>
</ead>
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I am after. I plugged it in and got an "IndexError: list index out of range."

Comment: `IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 45
     43 line = ' '.join(row).split(';')
     44 # Excel column0:<titleproper>; column1:<unittitle>; column2:<eadid>; column3:<unitid>; column6:<unitdate>
---> 45 row = [line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4]]
     46 create_XML(row, no)
     47 no += 1

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I am not clear on what you mean Cell ln[6], line 45. I am looking at the original Excel file at line 45 but I am not sure what info you are after

Comment: I think my issue may be the CSV file itself. The line[4] was my error. I cannot seem to get a CSV with a ; delimiter. I am using a mac with Excel and numbers and perhaps that is my issue?

Comment: it's the most bizarre thing in Numbers. It asks me the delimiter I want and I choose ; and it still gives me the comma.

Comment: I ended up being able to get it formatted correctly using NeoOffice. However, the error I am getting now is "AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'indent'

Comment: I used python V 3.11, see [here](https://github.com/BalzGuenat/CustomThreads/issues/1)

Comment: thank you so much for working through this with me. It appears to be working perfectly. The only thing that isn't working are the two dates - I cannot seem to get them between the two quotation marks in <unitdate normal=""></unitdate>. For whatever reason they are coming out like this: <unitdate normal="">1811/2003</unitdate>

Comment: This was my failure in the first posted solution and should be fixed, if you follow the updated code above: `unitdate = root.find('.//unitdate', ns)       unitdate.attrib['normal'] = row[4]` . Find also some best practice for unitdate in my answer above what i found at https://eadiva.com/unitdate/.  If this answer your question now, please accept or upvote my answer.

Comment: @Hermann12 `If you can save your Excel as a csv-file you don't need pandas` that's just wrong and the problems show why. Pandas isn't used to read Excel files, it's used to make working with data easier. Excel has proper number and date types while CSVs depend on using the correct delimiters and parsing fields using the correct formats

Comment: And `encoding='us-ascii'` is never used. Nobody uses the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage. This can't even handle all English words like `naïve` or `Brontë`. There's no reason anyway, UTF8 is *identical* in the range 0x00-0x7F.

Comment: It's *your* code that uses `us-ascii`. And yes, Pandas can help because it makes reading both CSV and Excel easier. I downvoted because the answer is wrong and made  things harder

Comment: The only "Pandas solution" you need is to pass the original code's `row` to your original `create_XML`. Row fields can be accessed by index and name. The comment about `xls` and `xlsm` is wrong. The Excel format is `xlsx` since 2007. `xlsm` is a macro-enabled workbook and rarely used for data interchange. `xls` is the obsolete format used before 2007. All formats work with Pandas as long as you install the correct library, openpyxl or xlrd